# Controlling a 5 V input with a 3.3 V ESP8266 via an opto-isolator

Tags: arduino, resistors, opto-isolator, esp8266

I want to control a 5 V input on another device with a ESP8266 by using a [PC817](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/73758.pdf) opto-isolator. I am using the following wiring:

[image: Wiring Diagram]

The output pin is connected to an Arduino-like microcontroller. I need the signal to update at a 0.5 ms rate (2 kHz).

Do the wiring and the values for the resistors seem correct? Should I go higher with the resistor values to be safe?

I am new to electronics, and I want to make sure everything is alright.

Comment: The value of R2 looks fairly low for when the output will just be used as a digital input to another device. You could probably change it to a higher value (like 4.7 k) for lower power consumption. It depends on the load and the switching speed needed at the output. Also consider that you're building an inverter. A high at the input will produce a low at the output and vice versa. Do you really need the two parts of the circuit to be galvanically isolated?

Comment: Assuming a 1.9 V voltage drop across the LED, the LED current would be about 4 mA. The optocoupler's datasheet can tell you if this is OK. As for the pull-up resistor: its value looks low if you are driving a digital input. What is connected to the Output Pin?

Comment: The output pin is connected to an Arduino like Microcontroller

Comment: @Yuukino What speed (rate, frequency, whatever) do you need? The PC817 isn't exactly a speed-demon (and also depending on what you can accept at the output.) So how fast, exactly?

Comment: I need the signal to update with a 0.5ms rate (it's emulating an NEC InfraRed signal)

Comment: Do you really need an opto-isolator?  You show the grounds on both sides connected together.  If the grounds are really connected, then the opto-isolator isn't really isolating. You could use a transistor instead.

Comment: Fair point about needing the Opto in the first place. And it is probably right that I don't NEED it. But if feels safer to isolate the two circuits (from my beginner perspective) so that I can't mess anything up on the more expensive target device. I don't care much if I fry a $2 ESP8266 :) also, it's a good excuse to learn about Optocouplers

Comment: If they share a ground then the opto isolator doesn't make it any safer - at all.  Learning about how opto-isolators work is a good thing, though.

Answer (score 3):

*Assuming* a 1.2 V forward voltage drop across the optocoupler's LED, the LED current would be \$\frac{3.3~\mathrm{V}-1.2~\mathrm{V}}{330~\Omega}\small\approx 6~\mathrm{mA}\$. The optocoupler's datasheet can tell you if this is enough, and what the LED's exact voltage drop is to do your own calculation.

As for the pull-up resistor: its value is quite low if you are driving a microcontroller's digital input. I would go for a 10 kΩ resistor and adjust if necessary. A microcontroller's inputs are high-impedance and you don't need much current to drive them at the speed you need.

You do need to ask yourself if you need an optocoupler at all, or maybe just a level-shifter, or even a direct connection. Also, if you want to make things safer, you will also have to separate the grounds.

Comment: Assuming the 4mA is enough for the optocoupler, then it should be fine, right? 4mA wouldn't be too much draw for an ESP8266 output pin, even if it's constant?

And regarding Optocoupler vs Levelshifter vs Direct - while I could probably safely go with a direct route, I just want to be uber safe here and figured nothing is safer than separating both circuits completely as long as it works :)

Answer (score 1):

330 on the 3V side one side 470 on the 5V side:

You're asking for a current transfer ratio of about 100%  very few opto-isolators perform that well.  [The data sheet](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/73758.pdf) for this one says 50% which
Is higher than I am used to.

The data sheet suggests 5mA as the LED current. The 330 ohm resistor will get you close to that, it's one of the sizes keep plenty of in stock so I would probably forego increasing it slightly to get closer to 5mA.

Overdriving the LED reduces its life, so unless you need blinding speed, underclocking your parts can pay off.

On the output  10K is my favourite size, I look for a reason not to use 10K, and finding none use it.

In this case the saturation performance specified at 20mA for 1mA out is more like the 5% current transfer ratios I'm used to. That suggests 22K or even 33K might be a better pull-up. if you want to output to go really low and not just kind of low.